# Why do the MongoDB docs recommend not using DBREFs?

Tags: mongodb, join, reference

The [MongoDB docs for DBREFs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) say:

> Unless you have a compelling reason to use DBRefs, use manual references instead.

Why? DBREFs seem more easy to use, since they encode the database and collection names, which would lead to less hard-coding in the application. Plus, DBREF is [a standard format that many drivers understand](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#driver-support-for-dbrefs).

This question is related, but not exactly the same:

[MongoDB - is DBREF necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412341/mongodb-is-dbref-necessary)

The answer to that question is that embedding/denormalization is preferable to linking, but it doesn't answer the question of why manual linking is preferable to DBREFs.

Comment: In short, it's because it's overkill for most situations as you end up storing the same collection name in every single DBRef which bloats the size of your docs.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, that's a good point, but may not apply when using the WiredTiger storage engine https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-compression-options-mongodb-30

Answer (score 1):

Here a conclusion of all I viewed.

Using `DBRef` is not a `join` operation, it will automatically query the second or more times, depends on how much `DBRef` you have got in this collection fields.

Assuming you have a collection that its model has 10 `DBRef`, you make query for 10 elements' list of it and one of these `DBRef` is `really needed`. Once you query, Mongodb will runs `101(1 + 10*10)` queries, automatically, no matter you need these `DBRef` or not. If you query these field manually, just a few coding and only `11(1 + 1*10)` queries are needed.

So, what do you say?

Comment: sounds plausible, happy to mark correct as long as I can verify: you have a source for this information or an example of how to verify?

Comment: Well, tested just now. I enable the profiling in mongodb and make a query all for a Class A, which with 3 `DBRef` fields of Class B. The query returns 4 A. In log, it shows 1 query in collection A and 12 queries in collection B. You can test it yourself, it's hard to paste the logging message in comment.

Comment: Moreover, in the logging of `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`, it shows only one query.

Comment: That's a good point @Kroderia, but those refs are not populated automatically. From the docs: _The drivers [1] do not automatically resolve DBRefs into documents._ That means you still have the option to query the raw documents with unresolved references and save those requests.

Comment: @kroderia, it sounds like you're using an abstraction layer / OOM that is generating bad queries.

Comment: If this were a database, I'd say the query was too open ended. "ask for what you want" don't ask for everything. Not sure how this applies to Mongo though, but good discussion.